# Wrong textview is being updated

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

In the onCreate() method I am updating 2 TextViews to be blank. For some reason it is setting two other TextViews to be blank. I have followed my logic and can not see what is going wrong.

here is my onCreate() method.

```
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int purpleDrinks; //number of purple drinks
private int greenDrinks; //number of green drinks
private int redDrinks; //number of red drinks
private int blueDrinks; //number of blue drinks

private TextView purpleCount; //number of purple drinks display
private TextView greenCount; //number of green drinks display
private TextView redCount; //number of red drinks display
private TextView blueCount; //number of blue drinks display
private TextView purchaseConfirm; //displays what the user bought
private TextView outOfStock; //lets the user know when the item is out of stock.



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if ( savedInstanceState == null ) // the app just started running
      {
         purpleDrinks = 10; 
         greenDrinks = 10;
         redDrinks = 10;
         blueDrinks = 10;

      } // end if

     purpleCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.purpleCount);
     greenCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greenCount);
     redCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.redCount);
     blueCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blueCount);
     purchaseConfirm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.purchaseConfirm);
     outOfStock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outOfStock);

     purchaseConfirm.setText("");
     outOfStock.setText("");
     purpleCount.setText(purpleDrinks + "");
     greenCount.setText(greenDrinks + "");
     redCount.setText(redDrinks + "");
     blueCount.setText(blueDrinks + "");

}
```

here is the xml code: the ids are correct.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background= "#D5E3EA"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/greenCann"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:src="@drawable/greencan" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/redCann"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/greenCann"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/redcan" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/purpleCann"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/redCann"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/purplecan" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/blueCann"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/purpleCann"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bluecan" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/restockButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
    android:text="@string/restock" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/purpleCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/purpleCann"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/purpleCann"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/redCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/redCann"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/redCann"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/greenCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/greenCann"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/greenCann"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/blueCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blueCann"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/blueCann"
    android:text="TextView" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/outOfStock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/restockButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/purchaseConfirm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/outOfStock"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/outOfStock"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/outOfStock"
    android:text="TextView" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/greenCount"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/restockButton"
    android:text="@string/greenSoda2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/redCount"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/redCount"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="@string/redSoda"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/purpleCount"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/purpleCount"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:text="@string/purpleSoda"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/blueCount"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blueCount"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
    android:text="@string/blueSoda"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

here is a screenshot of the app:

[image: screenshot]

does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: Which two `TextViews` do you want to be blank?

Comment: the 2 stacked above the restock button.

Comment: this problem has been fixed... now when you click the cans, the number next to it is supposed to decrease by one. But, unfortunately, a number next to another can is being decreased. This is very frustrating!!!!

Comment: Check the id of textview which you are setting the decreased number.

Comment: I guess you are getting confused and jumbling up the references taken from the layout file(.xml) in your .java file while calling the findViewById().Take a closer look at the views you declared in the xml,there id's and then pass there corresponding id's in the findViewById()

Comment: Show code for updating

Comment: try cleaning your project. That helped me when something like this happened

Comment: yes delete the content of bin and then clean project to make sure all the files are compiled and generated again.

Comment: As suggested, try cleaning the project by going to Project-Clean..., select your project, then press OK. Sometimes ADT doesn't update ID references after you modify resource files (including XML layouts in your case. Other case like `strings.xml` may happen too).